# Flink - Changing deployment parameters that affects on going windows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Im using SlidingProcessingTimeWindows (Flink-1.18) with configureable parameters for size and slide.
Further more, I have another configureable parameter that decides if should I run a special calculation (implemented in "getResult" and in "Add" method of the AggregateFunction) based on the number of events contained in the window.
Those parameters can be changed on deployment.
Given that i'm using checkpointing mechanism, how a change in parameters value should affect an ongoing window with my scenarios ?

I tried to change only the parameter for the "special calculation" abd it seems like there is inconsistency in results.
I understand that probably already added events will not be run again with the new configurations.
Can you clarify to me how it works?

And what will happen to the windows if I redeploy the the App with different size and slide values.

Thanks in advance,
Orel.